# iOS Safari: portrait mode and window.screen.availWidth

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

iOS Safari portrait mode on an iPhone 6:

```
window.innerHeight = 331px
window.innerWidth = 667px
```

Yup, that looks about right. Now we try...

```
window.screenAvailWidth = 375px
window.screenAvailHeight = 647px
```

Hmmm. That seems backwards. Or am I missing something? Remember, in portrait mode, the screen is wider than it is tall.

For some context, I'm trying to compensate for the URL bar when the iPhone is in landscape mode, so something like:

```
window.screenAvailWidth - window.innerHeight = urlBarHeight
```

That seems about right for the height of the URL bar, but `width - height = height` seems counter-intuitive.

If this behavior is intentional with iOS, do most other mobile devices return similar, backwards-seeming values? If they do not, is there a clever work-around? I don't want to start browser-sniffing, if I can help it.